# How can I document objects that I don't have ownership over?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openui

I'm returning a `Page<SomeObject>` In my method endpoints. In my OpenAPI UI, how can I generate a description of the fields that come from `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` type.
Normally what I do is go to the Object that I want to document and annotate its fields with `@Schema(description = "some description")`. But I don't have access to the `Page` class. How can I document its fields?

I'm probably missing something simple here, but any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am using OpenAPI v3 and springdoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenApiCustomiser.

Let's say for example you have this controller:

@RestController
public class HelloController {

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
Page<PersonDTO> getPage() {
    return null;
}
```

}

Let's suppose you want add the description the Pageable element:

```
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser pageableOpenApiCustomiser() {
    return openApi -> {
        Schema pageableSchema = openApi.getComponents().getSchemas().get("Pageable");
        pageableSchema.setDescription("my description");
    };
}
```

The same logic applies for any other attribute you nned to customize.